# Encoding in Microsoft SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis

I made an SSIS package that exports data from Microsoft SQL Server and imports it into a .csv and mysql file. But, in the mysql data with Cyrillic are inserted in the form of hieroglyphs. But, everything is fine in the .csv file.
I use driver ODBC 5.3 unicode.
*I start to use proxy account and it work, but only when user is logged.*
**How make it works when user is logged off !?**
Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Unicode" is not an actual encoding (though some Microsoft software uses it as a by-word for UCS-2 or UTF-16). Can you post the relevant XML parts of your SSIS package that concern the conversion to/from text? As well as the collation you're using in your tables and data-flow?

Comment: collation data-flow i don't change, and xml parts ??

Comment: mysql: utf8. The conversation does nothing, it is an attempt to solve

Comment: That images looks like BIDS, as a side question are you still using SQL Server 2008? If so, as an FYI, 2008 is very close to end of support now, with less than 2 months left. You want to look at upgrade paths soon, if you can.

Comment: yes, its 2008. But, that doesn't change anything in the problem.

Comment: I think you should use the same encoding used in Flat File connection manager

Comment: But, flat file and mysql insert are parallel lines

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to simply replace OLE DB with ADO NET.

NO, it work if this account is logon(
How make it work ?